# mysql update multiple records using original dataset and not updated dataset

Tags: mysql, transactions, sql-update, locking

I have to adjust some id's between two databases to sync them I have about 10k update statements (across multiple tables) such as UPDATE table SET col = new_id WHERE col = old_id. The issue I am running into is id's are getting updated and then updated over themselves through further down code execution where it might have changed an id to 1 from 5 then later it says change id 1 to 4 but I want that to happen only on the original dataset not the "updated" dataset since records have already changed id's ahead of this one. I tried transactions but that didn't work.

Example Problem:

SQL 1: update itemid = 1 where itemid = 5 (2 records updated, 1 itemid =1 already exists so now 3 itemid = 1 exist)

SQL 2: update itemid = 4 where itemid = 1 (3 records update HOWEVER I only wanted 1 record to update, the original dataset before the previous query ran)

How do you go about this (a keyword or style of query/options I can look into)? There also multiple tables being updated during this if that would make a difference.

Thanks!

Thanks

Comment: hi, you could keep track of which were modified in the first update by fetching the rows or maintaining an additional column with the state of the task.

Comment: add another criteria like dates

Comment: Does mysql not have a way to do this internally like a transactional/locking data thingy figure this isn't that uncommon of an issue figured it would have built in functionality to handle this type of thing.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but this feature would require mind-reading skills from mysql, whether you intend to update only some or all the records that meet a certain crieria! The way to handle it in general is to provide a criteria that distinguishes between already updated records and the ones still waiting to be updated.

Comment: @Shadow Well I figured a flag/option set that says use the data available at this time while preforming this group of queries but I guess that isn't a thing. The only thing mysql needs to know is a snapshot of the data I want to query against within a "transaction set" like automatically creating a copy temporary tables to query against while updating only the primary table. O-well guess I'll have to write something myself with either temp tables or adding new flag columns to switch when data was updated since the tables don't have a columns I can use for this already. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Innodb does use multi-versioning for transactions, but if you issue an update itemid = 4 where itemid = 1 statement, it will update all records that match the criteria because this is what update statements are meant to do! If the 2nd update statement were executed in a different transaction than the first one without commiting the first transaction, then under default idolation level the 2nd transaction would not see the changes done by the first one and eould therefore update two rows only.

Comment: Probably update `itemid=5` to `1` and `itemid=1` to `4` at the exact same time using one query?